# Помогите составить код. Нужно задать массив и перемножить все положительные числа

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь сделать задачу. Цель- задать любой желаемый массив,отделить от него положительные числа и перемножить их. Я для начала попытался просто умножить их на 2,но даже это не выходит. Делал по подобию кода,найденного в интернете,получилось вот это. Что здесь неправильно?Можно ли сделать по другому-короче и проще?

```
          #include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int i;
    const int n=20;  // Çàäàë ðàçìåð ìàññèâà?
    double result = 1.0;
    int massiv[n]; // Çàäàë ìàññèâ?
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++);
    massiv[i]  = i-10;

        for( int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << massiv[i]  << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;   //Âûâåë?


    }   
    for( int i=0; i<n;i++)
    if(massiv[i] > 0) result *= massiv[i]; 
    else if (massiv[i]<0) {cout <<"Oshibka";} 
    else;
    std::cout << std::endl;  

    for( int i=0; i<n;i++)
     std::cout << massiv[i] << " ";
     std::cout << result << " ";
     std::cout << std::endl;
{
std::cin.ignore();
return 0;
}

getchar();
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83844/discussion-on-question-by-alexey--------).

Answer (score 1):

допустим у вас есть массив со значениями  с именем mass и переменная lenght с значение длины массива

```
int allSum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < lenght; i++){
     if(mass[i] > 0){
          allSum += mass[i];
     }

}
```